# How do I make math.random print a string

Tags: lua

how do you make `math.random` print a string
and not an int value from a table.

this is some of the code I wrote

```
local Menu = {"","",""}

local Item = math.random(1,#Menu)

print(Item)
```

Sorry if this is a question if like everyone knows. I just started scripting about 6 days ago. I coudnt find the answer anywhere on google so I decided to come here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua： How to get a random element from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824087/lua-how-to-get-a-random-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close: using `print(Menu[Item])` should do what you need.

You can also use `math.random(#Menu)`, as it's the same as `math.random(1,#Menu)`.