# Lua： How to get a random element from an array?

Tags: lua

How to get a random element from an array in Lua?
For example, there is an array:

```
array={"apple","orange","pear","dog","cat","goat"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a table element through the index operation `array[index]`. So in order to get a random element you simply need a random index of the interval [1;#array]  where #array is the number of elements in array.

```
local randomIndex = math.random(1, #array) -- or short math.random(#array)
local randomElement = array[randomIndex]
```

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.random

Answer (score 0):

Getting it by removing it and fill another table avoiding doubles...

```
do
 local array1 = {"apple", "orange", "pear", "dog", "cat", "goat"}
 local array2 = {}

 for i = 1, #array1 do
-- table.remove() returns removed value so it can be used as a value
  table.insert(array2, table.remove(array1, math.random(#array1)))
 end

 print(table.concat(array2, ', '))
 -- return table.concat(array2, ', ', 1, 1), array2 -- Possible return values
end
```

Putting out for example...

```
orange, pear, cat, goat, dog, apple
```